# WPF: DependencyProperty on custom control set to value, but the bound property on the ViewModel is set to null

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I'm trying to create a WPF ListView that can bind its SelectedItems property.

I inherit from ListView. When the ListView's SelectionChanged event is raised, I read the ListView's SelectedItems property, and set my DependencyProperty's value to it.

I then add a BetterListView object to the XAML and bind its SelectedItemsBindable property to the viewmodel.

And although it looks like everything works - when I break at the view model's set method, I see that although SelectedItemsBindable was set to a collection inside BetterListView, the viewmodel gets this value as null! What am I doing wrong?

```
class BetterListView : ListView
{
    [Bindable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public IList SelectedItemsBindable
    {
        get { return GetValue(SelectedItemsBindableProperty) as IList; }
        set
        {
            SetValue(SelectedItemsBindableProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsBindableProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SelectedItemsBindable",
        typeof(IList), 
        typeof (BetterListView),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new List<object>(), 
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var items = SelectedItems.Cast<object>().ToList();
        SelectedItemsBindable = items;
    }

    #region constructor

    public BetterListView()
    {
        SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, `SetValue` replaces the binding with a value, you'll need to use `SetCurrentValue` here instead.

Comment: Tried that just now, didn't help.

Comment: Your control works for me. There must be something wrong with a part of your code you haven't shown here. As a note, your "better" ListView is incomplete. There would also have to be a PropertyChangedCallback for the SelectedItemsBindable property that sets the SelectedItems property when the source (view model) property changes. The PropertyChangedCallback would also have to check if the source collection implements INotifyCollectionChanged, and if that's the case, attach (and detach) a handler for its CollectionChanged event.

Comment: Besides that, replace `GetValue(...) as IList` by `(IList)GetValue(...)`. If (for whatever reason) the value returned by GetValue is not an IList, you would rightly get an `InvalidCastException` instead of a `NullReferenceException`.